# Invalid path for Logical Volume when resizing

Tags: centos

I'm new to Centos 7 but I'm trying to move space from the home directory to the root directory. I'm using this question for reference: [How to move disk space from centos-home to centos-root](https://serverfault.com/questions/765302/how-to-move-disk-space-from-centos-home-to-centos-root)

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:

```
[root@ns537316 /]# lvscan
[root@ns537316 /]# pvscan
  No matching physical volumes found
[root@ns537316 /]# lvscan /dev/md3
  Command does not accept argument: /dev/md3.
[root@ns537316 /]# pvscan /dev/md3
  Command does not accept argument: /dev/md3.
[root@ns537316 /]# pvscan /dev/md3/
```

Comment: You are trying to do something you don't understand. `/dev/md3` is not an LVM volume but a mdraid software RAID device that can't be managed with LVM. Please edit your question to add the output of `lvscan` and `pvscan` and do not post screenshots but instead, copy/paste the information into the question and use the formatting tools.

Comment: @Sven Exactly why I said I was new to Centos 7. I did lvscan and pvscan and nothing popped up. I edited my question to show the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using LVM so you can't do what you want. In your setup, doing this is so complicated (if possiblbe at all) that I would strongly suggest to not even try it and instead back up everything  and start over with useful partition sizes (and LVM)